# Remove space from paste() above array in R

Tags: r

I have the following code snippet in R,

```
paste("V",as.character(c(1:6)))
```

which generate the following output for the array:

"V 1" "V 2" "V 3" "V 4" "V 5" "V 6"

The generated spaces in the array elements are unnecessary.

How can I remove the spaces in a short (one line) code?

Comment: Have you read about `?paste0`

Comment: Also you can use `sep=""`: `paste("V",as.character(c(1:6)), sep="")`

Comment: Another option: `gsub(" ", "", paste("V",as.character(c(1:6))))
`

Comment: Somebody please post the info from one or more of these comments as an answer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some of my favourite ways to do vectorised string interpolation in R:

```r
nums  <- as.character(1:6)

v  <- paste0("V", nums)    

v  <- sprintf("V%s", nums)

v  <- glue::glue("V{nums}")

v  <- R.utils::gstring("V${nums}")
```

In all cases, `v` is a character vector, `"V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6"`. In the `glue` example it is also of class `glue`.

The difference in speed between these very rarely matters and certainly would not in this case. However, you can find some benchmarks in the `glue` [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glue/vignettes/speed.html).